# Forward slashes in the names returned by JNDI query to LDAP server

Tags: java, escaping, ldap, jndi

I need to make several queries to LDAP directory server and I'm using JNDI directory facilities for it. Then I need to do some work with the objects from the query result using their distinguished names. Some of the entries returned by the server contain forward slash character, and because of this JNDI escapes the whole name with double quotes:

```
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = dirContext.search(queryRoot, queryFilter, controls);
for (SearchResult result : Collections.list(results)) {
    String objectName = result.getName();
    System.out.println(objectName);
}
```

If one of the objects in the query results has a name, say, 'b=id/10,a=1', it is printed like this

```
"b=id/10,a=1"
```

Note the double quotes around the name. Because of these quotes I cannot create `javax.naming.ldap.LdapName` from it directly: it fails with `NamingException` "Invalid name".

I understand that I can remove these quotes manually, but this feels hacky. Is there a way to avoid such escaping? Or maybe there are cleaner methods to do what I need?

P.S. It is funny that [official JNDI tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ldap/faq.html#20) suggests using `LdapName` to achieve "easy name manipulation" and even mentions the escape problem but does not provide any links on the problem described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an `AttributeValue` has LDAP-specific syntax, the characters are converted (using the defined syntax specification) to UTF-8 and only the following characters must be escaped:

- `' '` (space) at the beginning of the string
- `' '` (space) at the end of the string
- `'"'`
- `'+'` (the plus character indicates a multi-valued RDN)
- `,` (the comma character separates components of the distinguished name)
- `;`
- `<`
- `>`
- `\`

The forward slash is a valid character and need not be escaped, therefore it must be handled by the application and the API used by that application. As you noted, the forward slash has "special meaning" to JNDI. JNDI is poorly designed in many respects, this is only one of the many. Consider using the [UnboundID LDAP SDK](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldapsdk/) for new code.

For example, add the following entry:

```
dn: uid=abc/def,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
uid: abc/def
cn: abc/def
sn: abc/def
userPassword: this entry is used to test http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690529/forward-slashes-in-the-names-returned-by-jndi-query-to-ldap-server
```

retrieve the entry just added:

```
ldapsearch -h localhost -p 10389 -D 'cn=RootDn'  -b dc=example,dc=com -s sub '(uid=abc/def)' 1.1
Enter bind password: 
version: 1
dn: uid=abc/def,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
```

#### see also

- [string representation of distinguished names](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4514)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I cannot use anything but JNDI since I cannot add new external dependencies to the project. So, essentially you're saying that it is impossible to overcome this issue in a clean way? That's a pity...

Answer (score 0):

The search result return by SearchResult.getName() is of the form of `CompositeName`. Try to use it like this:

```
Name itemPart = new CompositeName(result.getName())
Name absoluteName = new LdapName(myBasePath).addAll(itemPart)
// or
String sAbsoluteName = ctx.composeName(new LdapName(myBasePath), itemPart)
```

Strange escaping will be removed from `absoluteName`.