# Can't use a SearchResult to delete a record (quotes escaped by double backslash)

Tags: ldap, jndi

I inserted a record into Ldap using JNDI. It's name is `c=""aa`. JNDI did a job of escaping that for me, so it landed in db as `c=\"\"aa`. Ok, that's what I expected considering all those escaping rules.

Now of course I want to delete this record. I can search for it and get its name. **The name should be good to delete the record**.

The problem is that the following code:

```
SearchResult sr = obtainSearchResultInJndiWay();
System.out.println("name: " + sr.getName())
```

returns `name: c=\\"\\"aa`.

**This doesn't work**. I can't delete such an item, because it is not found. I should delete the item `c=\"\"aa`, but I have no way to obtain the correct LdapName.

Should I convert double backslashes manually? I even found a third party code that does this. Is it another proof that JNDI is a poor concept, like in this question, about [forward slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11700539/772981)?

My solution is to forbid entering of slashes and quotes in ldap names. Is it a good workaround? What other traps may I expect? Is there any guide how to use JNDI for Ldap safely? These are questions of a guy who gets lost. To make the question more clear for Stack: **How to deal with this problem**?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved this. I believe this is undocumented feature. I dived into jdk source code and browsed to [src/share/classes/com/sun/jndi/ldap/LdapBindingEnumeration.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/com/sun/jndi/ldap/LdapBindingEnumeration.java). The key part is the following:

```
CompositeName cn = new CompositeName();
cn.add(atom);
```

So they treat the name to be returned as a `CompositeName`. Documentation of this class mentions extra escaping. Ok, once we know, what is the nature of the returned string, we can consume it the right way.

```
CompositeName compo = new CompositeName(sr.getName())
Name absolutePath = new LdapName(sBaseDn).addAll(compo)
// sBaseDn is the context (the address) in which the search was made.
```

The name obtained in this way has the required number of backslashes. It is capable of consuming all kind of weird characters I could invent, including forward slashes.